# Movie sponsorship

Tags: production

Can an organization sponsor the entire production of a movie especially when the movie is revolving around its brand?

Comment: **Can they?** Of course. They can do whatever they want. A company will be more likely to fund an entire movie if the movie is ultra-low budget.

Comment: I wonder who puts up the bulk of the money for the Lego movies? They've got to be the most single-minded 'product placement' ever, even if they do tend to be quite surprisingly good ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin ---wikipedia - *"The film's total cost, including production, promotion and advertising (P&A), was $100 million.Half of the film's cost was financed by Village Roadshow Pictures.] The rest was covered by Warner Bros., with RatPac-Dune Entertainment providing a smaller share as part of its multi-year financing agreement with Warner Bros"*

Comment: Lego must have thought it was xmas.

Comment: Similar to the Lego movies, _The Internership_ was set on the Google campus and extolled Google every chance it got. I'm not sure if Google put up any money, however.

Answer (score 1):

> Can an organization sponsor the entire production of a movie especially when the movie is revolving around its brand.

Of course...

## They are called "movie adverts"

That's essentially what an movie advert is...a motion picture made to advertise a brand or specific product.

Any company can make a movie, heck even *private individuals* have made movies financed on *credit cards*, so there is no reason a private company (such as Nestlé) couldn't do the same.

They just have to fork over the money to a production company.

Whether they could get a distribution deal *and* get people to go and see it is an entirely different question.